# how can I make a file created in a function readable by other functions?

Tags: python

I need the contents of a file made by some function be able to be read by other functions. The closest I've come is to import a function within another function. The following code is what is what I'm using. According to the tutorials I've read python will either open a file if it exists or create one if not.What's happening is in "def space" the file "loader.py" is duplicated with no content.

```
def load():                                # all this is input with a couple of filters
    first = input("1st lot#: ")            #
    last = input("last lot#: ")            #
    for a in range(first,last+1):          #
        x = raw_input("?:")
        while x==(""):
            print " Error",
            x=raw_input("?")
        while int(x)> 35:
            print"Error",
            x=raw_input("?")

        num= x    #python thinks this is a tuple
        num= str(num)

        f=open("loader.py","a")                 #this is the file I want to share
        f.write(num)      
    f.close()
    f=open("loader.py","r")                     #just shows that the file is being 
    print f.read()                              #appened
f.close()
print "Finished loading"    





def spacer():    
    count=0
    f=open("loader.py","r")                   #this is what I thought would open the 
                                              #file but just opens a new 1 with the
                                              #same name
    length=len(f.read())                      
    print type(f.read(count))
    print f.read(count)
    print f.read(count+1)
    for a in range(1,length+1):
        print f.read(count)
        vector1= int(f.read(count))        
        vector2 = int(f.read(count+1))
        if vector1==vector2:
            space= 0
        if vector1< vector2:    
            space= vector2-vector1
        else:
            space= (35-vector1)+vector2
            count=+1
            b= open ("store_space.py","w")
            b.write(space)           
    b.close()
load()
spacer()
```

### this what I get

```
1st lot#: 1  
last lot#: 1  
?:2
25342423555619333523452624356232184517181933235991010111348287989469658293435253195472514148238543246547722232633834632  
Finished loading        # This is the end of "def load" it shows the file is being appended
<type 'str'>            # this is from "def spacer" I realized python was creating another 
                        # file named "loader.py with nothing in it. You can see this in the 
                        #error msgs below
```

#### Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Python27/ex1", line 56, in <module>
    spacer()
File "C:/Python27/ex1", line 41, in spacer
vector1= int(f.read(count))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''tion within another function but this only causes the imported function to run.
```

Comment: make the file global of just open the file again in the other fnction

Comment: It might be useful to post some of your code here to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, use the right words for things. You can't possibly mean "import a function"—while you can import a function (e.g., `from mymodule import myfunction`) that doesn't run the imported function, it just makes the function available in your globals. On the other hand, if you import a _module_ (`import mymodule`) that runs any top-level code in the module (the first time only), but doesn't call any functions defined there. If you don't know how to use the right words, it's even _more_ important that you show us code.

Answer (score 0):

The file probably has content, but you're not reading it properly. You have:

```
count=0
#...
vector1= int(f.read(count))
```

You told Python to read 0 bytes, so it returns an empty string. Then it tries to convert the empty string to an `int`, and this fails as the error says, because an empty string is not a valid representation of an integer value.